# How to display the dropdown values based on other dropdown selected value using typescript in Angular 4

Tags: angular, api, events

I want to change dropdown value based on selected other dropdown selected.
this is HTML

```
 <select class="form-control" name="category_id" formControlName="category_id" (change)="changeProfession($event.target.value)">
                                    <!-- <option value="" d>Select Category (required)</option> -->
                                    <option *ngFor='let surveyCategory of surveyCategoryList' [ngValue]="surveyCategory._id">{{ surveyCategory.category }}</option>
                                    <app-field-error-display [displayError]="this.validationService.isFieldValid(updateProfileForm,'category_id')">
                                    </app-field-error-display>
                               </select>
```

here I want to get value as per the selected category

```
<div class="form-group label-floating select_lang">
                                <label class="control-label">Profession</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="profession_id" formControlName="profession_id" >
                                     <!-- <option value="" >Select Category (required)</option> -->
                                    <option *ngFor='let profession of ProfessionList' [ngValue]="profession._id">{{ profession.profession }}</option>
                                    <app-field-error-display [displayError]="this.validationService.isFieldValid(updateProfileForm,'profession_id')">
                                    </app-field-error-display>
                               </select>

                            </div>
```

this is the ts file

```
changeProfession(categoryid){
    debugger;
    this.authService.getProfessionList(categoryid).subscribe(data => {
        debugger;
        if (data.success) {
            debugger;
            this.ProfessionList = data.profession;
            console.log(data);
            setTimeout(() => {
            //if (obj.survey_category_id)
                    //this.updateProfileForm.controls['profession_id'].setValue(obj.profession_id._id);
                 $('.select_lang').removeClass('is-empty');
            }, 10);
        }

    });
}
```

and this is the service file

```
// Get survey profession list
 getProfessionList = function (categoryid) {
     debugger;
    return this.http.get(this.api_url + 'profession/list/'+ categoryid, this.getAuthHeaderOption()).map(res => res.json());
}
```

When I am calling this event then category id is passing but value in not showing.
Please tell me what I am doing wrong here .

Comment: Are you getting "data" correctly in console?

Comment: Only I am getting category id

Comment: like this `4: 5ae385afa4723d1858b0c239`

Comment: when I am debugging it then after calling the `.subscribe`  it is get finished and not going inside  this`if (data.success) {
            debugger;
            this.ProfessionList = data.profession;
            console.log(data);`

Comment: if I am checking on postman and doing like this `http://IPADDRES:DOMIAN/profession/list/5a745ef7eba43102e6038881` then it giving me this below output
`{"status":200,"success":true,"message":"list","profession":[{"_id":"5c2f65ab1f798017909615af","profession":"ss"}]}`

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong here .

Comment: could you add this additional information from the comments into the question?
It makes it easier to understand the issue.
If you call `console.log(data)` right before yor if-statement, is the data correct/as expected?

Comment: Actually whats happening here after `.subscribe` it is not going inside `if (data.sucess)`
`consol.log(data)`

Comment: if I am checking same this on postman 
`http://IPADDRESS:domain/profession/list/5a745ef7eba43102e6038881`  then it is giving me below output
`{"status":200,"success":true,"message":"list","profession":[{"_id":"5c2f65ab1f798017909615af","profession":"ss"}]}` which I am expecting to get

Comment: above I am passing category id to get relevant profession like `"profession":"ss"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular way of implementing your requirement will be slight different than the way you have done.

in your `component.ts` file add below code where you have initialize the form :

```
 this.sampleForm.controls['category_id'].valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
       this.authService.getProfessionList(value).subscribe(data => {
            this.ProfessionList = data.profession;
       }); 
 });
```

replace `sampleForm` with your `formGroup` Name. Also note that the value of `data.profession` should be array of objects.

> Here is sample working Stackblitz link : [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wnxrma)

Comment: So Don't we need to create change event as I did ?

Comment: Why would you write your own change controller when angular already provided one

Comment: Thanks a lot really it work for me, even I was stucking for a long time but now I got rid off from this issue.

Comment: which one angular  provides change controller  ?

Comment: @Hi are you there